# Processing Lists of char * in C?

Tags: c, lisp

I need to perform various functions on long lists of strings in C.

```
char *list1[] = {"one","two","three", "four","five","six"};
```

Initially, I'm trying to implement simple car/cdr functions, but it has been a while and I forget the best way to manage lists of char *[] in C.  cdr should return the rest of the list of char *'s in a freshly malloc'ed array.  In my case, it's "two","three", "four","five","six".  The list size being unknown complicates this.  Perhaps, I should be using a struct with the list length?

```
char **cdr(char *aList[]) {
  /*
   malloc space for n-1 char*
  */
  return aList; // Return everything to test
}
```

I'll have other functions, say, for example, return the list of all words with two consecutive vowels, or words longer than 10 characters.  I will never want to change the strings (ie. they're immutable).  I'll be malloc'ing the memory in functions like cdr so I'll need to keep track of that as I take my results and pass them to other functions.  Anyway, if someone could get me started, it would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
char *list1[] = {"one","two","three", "four","five","six"}; // Short list

char **cdr(char *aList[]) {
  /*
   malloc space for n-1 char*
  */
  return aList; // Return everything to test
}

char *car(char *aList[]) {
  return aList[0];
}

int main() {
  const char *first;
  char *rest[];

  int len = sizeof(list1)/sizeof(char*);
  printf("list1 len=%d\n", len);

  first = car(list1);
  rest = cdr(list1);

  printf("%s\n", first);
  len = sizeof(rest)/sizeof(char*);
  printf("rest len=%d\n", len);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: " Perhaps, I should be using a struct with the list length?" -- Perhaps you should be using a cons list. Otherwise, you shouldn't be using the names "car" and "cdr".

Comment: "sizeof(rest)/sizeof(char*);" --- Wrong wrong wrong so wrong. We get about 2-3 questions on SO per day that misunderstand `sizeof`. It's a **compile-time** construct that only knows the size of variables, not their contents.

Comment: I hope you don't answer everyone with "wrong wrong wrong so wrong"  Not everyone started their career with C like me and you might discourage people from learning C.  It has been over a decade for me so I've done any serious work so I'm pretty rusty.  I've gone soft with Java. :-)  As for car/cdr, that's kind of pointless advice. car is the first result and cdr is the rest.  In short, next time just point to the FAQ.  Thanks.

Comment: There was nothing pointless or otherwise invalid about my comment. And if it discourages people from learning C, that wasn't my intention but it would be a good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list size being unknown not so much "complicates" this as "makes it impossible". If you don't want to pass explicit lengths around, you need to use a NULL value as a terminator.

```
int length(const char* strings[]) {
    int rv = 0;
    while( strings[rv] ) ++rv;
    return rv;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf( "Note that this technique is also used in argv: %p\n", argv[argc] );

    const *list[] = { "+", "42", "30", NULL };
    printf( "Length: %d\n", length( list ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Using such a length() in your other functions you should then be able to know the appropriate amount of memory to allocate. (Remember that you need to allocate space for an extra pointer for the NULL!)

Answer (score 2):

Typically lists as those you are  looking for are not implemented as arrays but as linked lists. The way they were first implemented is even the reason why the operations are called "car" and "cdr" (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR).

Lists implemented that way just consist of elements containing two pointers. So for your example such a list would look like this:

```
 +-----+-----+    +-----+-----+    +-----+-----+         +-----+-----+   
 | car | cdr | -> | car | cdr | -> | car | cdr | -> .... | car | cdr | -> NIL
 +-----+-----+    +-----+-----+    +-----+-----+         +-----+-----+
   |                 |                |                     |
   v                 v                v                     v
 "one"             "two"            "three"               "six"
```

To achive the same in C you'd rather use a struct like the following for the elements of the list:

```
struct _Element {
  struct _Element *cdr;
  void  *car;
};
```

If you still want to stay with the array approach instead best take a look at "svk"s post. Using NULL terminated arrays instead of separately keeping track of the length might be an interesting alternative to the version you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

All that mallocing and freeing in C is both wasteful and error-prone. Why not just return the actual strings?

```
char * car (char ** list) {
    return list[0];
}

char ** cdr (char ** list) {
    return list + 1;
}
```

Comment: cdr()/rest() is just one example.  I might want to split the list into 4 smaller lists, for example, or return all the words that start with "he".